# Unable to install a distro on a Macbook

Tags: installation, acquia-dev-desktop

I recently upgraded Acquia Dev Desktop 2 with the most recent release as of March 23th, for both Windows and Mac. It works great on my Windows machine however, while on my Macbook I'm unable to Install a Drupal 8 Distro or any other Disto available from the pop-up list.

I've tried uninstalling Dev Desktop (*while removing all my site/program folders associated with dev desktop*) and reinstalling Dev Desktop to find it hasn't resolved the problem.

[image: image displaying the broken Install link for Drupal 8 in dev desktop]

Is it possible this issue could be application based or am I forgetting a step that is causing the installation not to work?

Comment: There isn't something like a hidden Mac prompt buried under one of the windows is there?

Comment: Nope, I checked for that too.

Comment: That's weird... it has been a very long time since I have used DevDesktop. Would you be able to use something like DrupalVM?

Comment: I could give it a try. I've been using my Windows machine for a temp fix, but yeah i had a few collages try it on their macbooks and they had the same thing happen to them. I'm starting to think it might be the application itself.

Comment: Very possible. Jeff G recently wrote some articles on getting DrupalVM running on Windows 7-10. I personally have been able to get it running on Windows too, but yeah it does work better on Mac/Linux.

Comment: It's also possible this is a regression. I'm using an older version of ADD and the installs work just fine... but there have been issues in the past with other versions.

Comment: So I was playing around last night and I found a work around. So if you go to drupal.org and download a copy of D8 and place a copy in your designated sites folder like magic when you start up DD it magically appears in the site list, and you can run through the install like you normally would. Doesn't resolve the Install link problem but I got it working.